# concatenating the columns of two from dataframe

Tags: r

I Have a summary like below and I want to concatenate the columns with ":"

```
df <- data.frame(" " = "SLA",
                 T1 = c(2341),
                 T2 = c(5543),
                 T3 = c(6543),
                 T4 = c(646))
```

the output should be like
i want to make it dynamic, this i can do but wanted to maked it dynamic which can combine 2:3rd column and 4:5th column

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a simple for-loop will help

```
df1<- data.frame(' ' = 'SLA')
n <- ncol(df)

for (i in seq(2,n-1,2)){
  df1[,1+i/2] <- paste(df[,i], df[,i+1], sep = ' : ')
  colnames(df1)[1+i/2] <- paste(colnames(df)[i], colnames(df)[i+1], sep = ' : ')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using "tidyverse" package:

```
    df <- data.frame(" " = "SLA",
             T1 = c(2341),
             T2 = c(5543),
             T3 = c(6543),
             T4 = c(646))

    #install.packages("tidyverse")
    library(tidyverse)

    df <- df %>%
    unite("T1:T2", T1:T2, sep= ":", 
    remove = TRUE)

    df <- df %>%
    unite("T3:T4", T3:T4, sep= ":", 
    remove = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to character and concatenate elements with `paste`

```r
n <- ncol(df) - 1
for(i in seq_len(n/2))
{
  df[[paste0("T", i, " : T", i + 1)]] = paste(df[[paste0("T", i)]], df[[paste0("T", i + 1)]], sep = " : ")
}
```

Comment: i want to make it dynamic, this i can do but wanted to maked it dynamic which can combine 2:3rd column and 4:5th column